# I need to prove the following

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following proposition: For all $m,n \in\mathbb Z$, $-m < -n$ if and only if $m > n$. I know that if and only if means that I need to prove both ways, right?
Proof: 
\begin{align*}
-m < -n\\
-n--m \in\mathbb N\\
-n + -(-m) \in\mathbb N\\
-n + m \in\mathbb N\\
m - n \in\mathbb N
\end{align*}

However, why would I now need to do the reverse? It seems redundant because I have shown that $m > n$ is the same as $-m < -n$, no?

UPDATE, here is the second part of the proof
\begin{align*}
m - n \in\mathbb N\\
-(-m) - n \in\mathbb N\\
-n -(-m) \in\mathbb N\\
-n > -m
\end{align*}

It's essentially the exact reverse. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the reverse because your proposition includes the phrase "if and only if". So your statement "$-m < -n$ if and only if $m > n$" means:

Forward direction: If $-m < -n$, then $m > n$.

Backward direction: If $m > n$, then $-m < -n$.

And these are both statements you must prove. If you do not prove both directions, then you have not proved the "if and only if".

Comment: Thank you! Ok, so I simply need to do the exact reverse, right?

Comment: You're welcome. :) Exactly, prove the reverse. Sometimes, the proof in the reverse direction may not be the same as the proof in the forward direction.

Comment: Hi! I have finished the second part. I'd greatly appreciate if you could please look at my proof. Thank you!

Comment: For your original direction, you want to start at $-m < -n$ and finish at $m > n$. You do not want to finish with "$m-n \in \mathbb{N}$". In fact, you do not need the "$\in \mathbb{N}$" anywhere in your forward statement. The same is true for your reverse statement. As far as your understanding of the reverse direction goes, I think you got it. Here, the reverse direction does include the exact steps in reverse.